# ImportError:no module named hello_ecto

Tags: ros, python, object-recognition, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,i am using ubuntu12.04+groovy.i followed [ecto](http://plasmodic.github.io/ecto/ecto/install/get_ecto.html#dependencies)

when i run `python ecto/samples/hello.py`,i got error below:

root@baogege:~/catkin_ws/src/ecto_kitchen# python ecto/samples/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ecto/samples/hello.py", line 30, in

```
import ecto.hello_ecto as hello_ecto #a user library, that has a few ecto modules
```

ImportError: No module named hello_ecto

anyone can help me?thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215470/importerror:no-module-named-hello_ecto/) by [baogege](https://answers.ros.org/users/22605/baogege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2016-01-03**:
Have you solved it? I met the same problem. Thanks!

**Comment by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on 2017-01-17**:
run `. ~/ecto_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure your run the setup.bash

```
. ~/ecto_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) with karma: 38 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0